# Need Clarification on AC to DC Conversion Calculations

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, charging

[This question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/what-is-more-cost-effective-re-charging-a-car-battery-or-replacing-it-new-when) from the mechanics.SE site got a bit of an electrical argument going. Basically, dude was asking if it's cheaper to charge a dead car battery or buy a new one. Of course it's cheaper to charge a dead car battery (as long as it can still hold a charge), but the argument started around the proper math for it.

**Question:** when considering using AC mains to charge a DC battery, which quantity is conserved? The Coulombs or the Joules?

Comment: You are typically charged by Watt-Hours which is a unit of energy equal to 3600 Joules.  Not sure what you are asking about which quantity is conserved.  Energy is conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work a lot with electricity including conversion, in mains AC power, electric drives, off-grid/solar, electronics and automotive.

I know a joule is a watt-second (making joules-per-second, a Star Trek unit, quite amusing.)   *It took some detective work to figure out what a coulomb is.*

[image]

Turns out, it's *not* a Space Shuttle.

**The number of electrons in an amp** is not a particularly useful number, partly because **none of the electrons in the mains power actually go into the battery**. Generally they whirl around a transformer core, which induces *other* electrons in another winding to get happy feet.  9-20 times as many, due to the magic of electromagnetism, though with a fraction of the verve.  Ultimately it ends up being not worth thinking about.

So no, number of electrons is definitely not preserved.

Watts and joules, pretty close, that dance is rather efficient. Thank you Mr. Tesla.